# How to solve PayPal PHP with laravel timed out error

Tags: php, paypal

I'm currently working with [this package](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) with laravel, but every time I pay with my paypal account and loads too slow, it returns an error. But if it loads fast, it works fine. Please see the screenshot below. Any idea about this?

[image]

Comment: This is a nice tutorial for paypal integration in laravel , Can you have a look into this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEetD9ZM45o&list=PLe30vg_FG4OSdVn4zFpXNpBILtijJ2-x7

Comment: @Ajith I appreciate your answer. But it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code into config>paypal.php file

```html
<?php 
return [ 
    'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID',''),
    'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SECRET',''),
    'settings' => array(
        'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE','sandbox'),
        'AUTHENTICATION_STATUS'=>'X',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'LANDINGPAGE'=>'Billing',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal_new.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'
    ),
];
```

Comment: Any explanation to your answer?

Comment: Hi jonjie, here you can change your time out using 'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,